# Get IP of app for A record (DNS)

Tags: swisscomdev

I'm trying to set up my DigitalOcean DNS to point the base domain to my app on the Swisscom cloud. As far as I can see, this is done with the A record which requires an IP - however I fear that the Swisscom app does not have a static IP? Is this correct? How could I in that case solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You're right, an A record won't work. For subdomains (e.g. www.example.com), you can simply use a CNAME record instead. However, for the APEX (e.g. example.com), CNAME records are not available and you need to redirect it by other means.

See also:
https://docs.developer.swisscom.com/devguide/deploy-apps/routes-domains.html#domains-dns

Comment: OK thank you. I've now set up forwarding since no ALIAS or ANAME are not available, however I'm not able to create an SSL certificate for the domain in the developer console ("verify that you have a CNAME pointing to <host>.scapp.io"). How should this CNAME record look like exactly?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question correctly. But you can't create a cert for the APEX, since the APEX is not pointing to the app directly anyway. The APEX cert needs to be created and installed where you set up the redirect. But if you e.g. forward the APEX to www.yourdomain.com and that domain is set up as a CNAME to your app, you can create the cert for www.yourdomain.com through the dev console.